# Itext barcode under text

Tags: java, itext

When I create a image using `code128.createImageWithBarcode()`  the text under barcode appears in the doc, but when I try to create using `createAwtImage` and later saving it to disc, the text under the barcode dissapear. Any idea about how to handle it?

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
code128.setCode(code.trim());
code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
Image code128Image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
java.awt.Image imgShipBarCode =  code128.createAwtImage(Color.white, Color.black);
int w = imgShipBarCode.getWidth(null);
int h = imgShipBarCode.getHeight(null);
int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;  // other options
BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
Graphics2D g2 = dest.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(imgShipBarCode, 0, 0, null);
g2.dispose();
File outputfile = new File("c:\\image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(dest, "jpg", outputfile);     
code128Image.setAbsolutePosition(10,700);
code128Image.scalePercent(125);
doc.add(code128Image);
```

Thanks

Comment: createAwtImage just returns the image, that by design. If you want text or anything else you'll have to compose it using the awt resources.

Answer (score 0):

Set Font to null

> `code128.Font = null;`

Comment: While this answer may solve the question, it is really low quality and should get an explanation how and why setting the font to `null` solves the question. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11144408)

Comment: @Paulo Soares comment down the question is right , createAwtImage just returns the image.